# Why help does this assigning value to a particular variable gives in the following model?

Tags: function, variables, deep-learning, pytorch

everyone I am working on a model in pytorch and my code is as follows:

```
def test_data(mdl):
    #Input new data
    age=float(input("What is the person's age? (18-90) "))
    sex=input("What is the person's sex? (Male/Female) ").capitalize()
    edx=input("What is the person's education level? (3-16)")
    ms=input("what is the person's martial status?")
    wcs=input("what is the person's workclass?")
    ocs=input("What is the person's occupation?")
    wrk_hrs=input("How many hours/week are worked?")
    
    #Preprocess the data
    sex_d={"Male":1,"Female":0}
    mar_d={"Married":1,"Single":0,"Civil-Partnership":2,"union":3,"Divorced":4,"Widowed":5}
    wrk_d = {'Federal-gov':0, 'Local-gov':1, 'Private':2, 'Self-emp':3, 'State-gov':4}
    occ_d = {'Adm-clerical':0, 'Craft-repair':1, 'Exec-managerial':2, 'Farming-fishing':3, 'Handlers-cleaners':4,
            'Machine-op-inspct':5, 'Other-service':6, 'Prof-specialty':7, 'Protective-serv':8, 'Sales':9, 
            'Tech-support':10, 'Transport-moving':11}
    sex=sex_d[sex]
    ms=mar_d[ms]
    wcs=wrk_d[wcs]
    ocs=occ_d[ocs]

cats=torch.tensor([sex,ms,wcs,ocs],dtype=torch.int64).reshape(1,-1)
conts=torch.tensor([wrk_hrs,age],dtype=torch.float32).reshape(1,-1)

model.eval()

with torch.no_grad():
    z=model(cats,conts).argmax().item()
print(f'\nThe predicted label is {z}')

test_data(model)
```

But I am confused as to what this part does

```
    sex=sex_d[sex]
    ms=mar_d[ms]
    wcs=wrk_d[wcs]
    ocs=occ_d[ocs]
```

**I needed to know what this above part performs and how do this works because I have no idea of what this part of the code is doing. Can someone please tell

Comment: Your indentation is broken. Python manages scope via indentation, the last part of your code is not inside the scope of the test_data method

Comment: Thanks I have editted my question could you answer this please as well?

Answer (score 1):

Python manages scope via indentation. Your indentation is broken, you are trying to reference variables outside the scope of the test_data method. Learn more about scope in Python here: https://www.w3schools.com/PYTHON/python_scope.asp

Change your code to the following:

```
def test_data(mdl):
    #Input new data
    age=float(input("What is the person's age? (18-90) "))
    sex=input("What is the person's sex? (Male/Female) ").capitalize()
    edx=input("What is the person's education level? (3-16)")
    ms=input("what is the person's martial status?")
    wcs=input("what is the person's workclass?")
    ocs=input("What is the person's occupation?")
    wrk_hrs=input("How many hours/week are worked?")
    
    #Preprocess the data
    sex_d={"Male":1,"Female":0}
    mar_d={"Married":1,"Single":0,"Civil-Partnership":2,"union":3,"Divorced":4,"Widowed":5}
    wrk_d = {'Federal-gov':0, 'Local-gov':1, 'Private':2, 'Self-emp':3, 'State-gov':4}
    occ_d = {'Adm-clerical':0, 'Craft-repair':1, 'Exec-managerial':2, 'Farming-fishing':3, 'Handlers-cleaners':4,
            'Machine-op-inspct':5, 'Other-service':6, 'Prof-specialty':7, 'Protective-serv':8, 'Sales':9, 
            'Tech-support':10, 'Transport-moving':11}
    sex=sex_d[sex]
    ms=mar_d[ms]
    wcs=wrk_d[wcs]
    ocs=occ_d[ocs]

    cats=torch.tensor([sex,ms,wcs,ocs],dtype=torch.int64).reshape(1,-1)
    conts=torch.tensor([wrk_hrs,age],dtype=torch.float32).reshape(1,-1)

    model.eval()

    with torch.no_grad():
        z=model(cats,conts).argmax().item()
    print(f'\nThe predicted label is {z}')

    test_data(model)
```

Comment: Okay I have fixed this but Now I have two other factors that I need to understand first one is mention in the question which I have editted and the other part is that now my code runs fine but it is giving me an error of "Index out of range in self". Can you tell me whats wrong with my code??

Comment: The edited part of your question maps the input from the command line to numerical values as defined in the sex_d, mar_d, wrk_d, occ_d dicitionaries

Comment: Please post a full error message and stacktrace